# RichTextBox losing formatting

Tags: c#, .net, formatting, richtextbox

I'm trying to make a dynamic RichTextBox-collection - where users can add several boxes - edit them and save to DB.

Case 1 (one and only)

- Pasting RTF data from wordpad document into the RTB-control.
- Formatting is as it should be:

  > {\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\deflang1044{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset0 Times New Roman;}{\f1\fnil\fcharset0 Microsoft Sans Serif;}}\r\n\viewkind4\uc1\pard\lang20\f0\fs40 Wattup?\lang1044\f1\fs17\par\r\n}\r\n
- Saving to DataSet (datatype Byte[]), Converting like this:

  ```
  public Byte[] toByteArray(string str)
  {
      System.Text.ASCIIEncoding encoding = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding();
      return encoding.GetBytes(str);
  }
  ```
- Loading from DataSet - creating new instances of RichText-Boxes. Converting like this:

  ```
  public string fromByteArray(Byte[] bytes)
  {
      System.Text.ASCIIEncoding enc = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding();
      return enc.GetString(bytes);
  }
  ```
- Loading from DataSet - applying the data i have saved to the Rtf property of the new RTB.
  Rtf property is still as it should be.
- Loading the Control - Formatting ends up like this:

  > {\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\deflang1044{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset0 Microsoft Sans Serif;}}\r\n\viewkind4\uc1\pard\lang20\f0\fs17 Wattup?\lang1044\par\r\n}\r\n

In conclusion - pasting RTF into the control works fine - but loading the very same RTF-data into a "non-loaded" RTB seems to fail.

Would the RichTextBox-control apply some sort of auto-formatting to the RTF if the property is set before the visual loading of the component?

There's probably a simple solution to this.. Any Ideas?

Comment: Assign the Rtf property when you reload, not the Text property.  Hehe.

Comment: You've posted the encoding code, seems alright. The problem is likely to be in the Db and/or RTB interfacing.

Comment: In addition to Henk's comment. You might want to change the ASCIIEncoding to the same encoding that you're using in the db

Comment: Thanks - i'm setting the Rtf-property. Had i set the text-property i recon i would have seen the rtf-code in my component. The core of the problem is not related to the DB or the encoding - the rtf ends up with a different font and an all together different formatting.